# tkinter can't save data from entry to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The code works pretty good except from the `.get()` that doesn't retrieve the string from the `Entry` box into my new text file.

```
import tkinter

def save_register():

    full_name_info = full_name.get()
    email_info = email.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    with open("RegistrationInfo.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("username: " + full_name_info + "\n")
        f.write("email: " + email_info + "\n")
        f.write("password: " + password_info + "\n")

        full_name_entry.delete(0, 100)
        email_entry.delete(0, 100)
        password_entry.delete(0, 100)

    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="Registration completed", fg="green").pack()
```

---- New Window ----

```
def new_user():

    global screen1
    global full_name
    global email
    global password
    global full_name_entry
    global email_entry
    global password_entry

    screen1 = tkinter.Tk()
    screen1.geometry("300x300")
    screen1.title("register page")

    full_name = tkinter.StringVar()
    email = tkinter.StringVar()
    password = tkinter.StringVar()

    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="Welcome please enter info below").pack()
    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="").pack()
    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="Full name:").pack()
    full_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(screen1, textvariable=full_name, width=25)
    full_name_entry.pack()
    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="Email:").pack()
    email_entry = tkinter.Entry(screen1, textvariable=email, width=25)
    email_entry.pack()
    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="Password:").pack()
    password_entry = tkinter.Entry(screen1, textvariable=password, width=25)
    password_entry.pack()
    tkinter.Label(screen1, text="").pack()
    tkinter.Button(screen1, text="Register", command=save_register).pack()
```

So I'm not really sure what is wrong here I will be more than happy if anyone will figure it out.

Comment: I can't tell from the code snippets in your question, but suspect that you may be calling `tkinter.Tk()` more than once — which generally is not going to work in a tkinter app as you're finding out. To avoid doing that, call [`tkinter.Toplevel()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429194251id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) to create additional windows. Note you will still need to call `Tk()` once at the beginning of the program's execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the culprit is here but I suspect it has something to do with the use of StringVar within tkinter.

From everything I've read, StringVar is a completely valid way to obtain the data that has been entered into your entry boxes.

However, I personally had some issues implementing StringVar into my own GUI program recently. Instead, I just used the .get method as follows:

```
full_name=''

full_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(screen1, width=25)
full_name_entry.pack()

full_name = full_name_entry.get()
```

I was then able to manipulate the data mathematically throughout the rest of my program. StringVar and IntVar is also made for this purpose, so sticking with that method is understandable.

[This guide to StringVar](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) was one of the more readable guides I read when faced with this same issue. It walks through the different Var types in tkinter and how to implement them.